# How to set one content to several buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some buttons -in different windows- that have the same content. But if two windows surfaced together,out of the first window's button content disappears.

Buttons Style is :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BSaveBtn">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="68"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource FlatGreen}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource FlatGreenBtnHover}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <Image Width="30" Source="/login;component/img/buttonpic/save.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="save" FontSize="16" FontFamily="/login;component/fonts/#Droid Arabic Kufi" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

button Code in windows is :

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource BSaveBtn}" Template="{DynamicResource FlatGreenBtnHover}" />
```

problems occurs only with content -not another style properties- .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of an element can only appear *once* in the visual tree. You can set the x:Shared attribute of the Style to False in order for a new instance of the StackPanel to get created for each Button to which you apply the style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BSaveBtn" x:Shared="False">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="68"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource FlatGreen}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource FlatGreenBtnHover}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                <Image Width="30" Source="/login;component/img/buttonpic/save.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="save" FontSize="16" FontFamily="/login;component/fonts/#Droid Arabic Kufi" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me when I tested it here.

A few things I noticed though that may help. You don't need them to be DynamicResource, they should really be StaticResource unless you plan on modifying them.

I assume you are declaring these in the Windows.Resource section or repeating them on each window? 
If so you should centralize those to a ResourceDictionary.

Create a new Resource Dictionary put your style in there like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="BSaveBtn">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="70"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="68"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource FlatGreen}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource FlatGreenBtnHover}"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
                    <Image Width="30" Source="/login;component/img/buttonpic/save.png"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="save" FontSize="16" FontFamily="/login;component/fonts/#Droid Arabic Kufi" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in your App.xaml put the following:

```
<ResourceDictionary>    
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResources.xaml" />    
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The Image should really be in a dictionary to avoid loading it multiple times. Just add a line in that ResourceDictionary like so:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="/login;component/Images/Save.png" x:Key="Save" PresentationOptions:Freeze="True" />
```

Setting the PresentationOptions:Freeze will also help if the image is never being modified.

Your call to the image would then change to be:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <Image Width="30" Source="{StaticResource Save}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="save" FontSize="16"      FontFamily="/login;component/fonts/#Droid Arabic Kufi" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Once your resources are centralized in a ResourceDictionary (or multiple) it makes it easy to apply those same styles anywhere in your application and hopefully will help with your issue. If not please give more info on the problem you have such as sample code to make the issue happen please.